# Android ListView with SQL and SDcard data's

Tags: android, listview, lazy-loading, adapter, sd-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android - How do I do a lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

I have a custom list of contacts. It contains the name, description (from the database) and the corresponding image from the file system. SimpleCursorAdapter not work with icons. How to make lazy initialization list with this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at this nice [article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html),

Also [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/10/android-listview-example-with-image-and.html),